# How to write a File with text from a TEdit(Textbox)

Tags: c++, text-files, c++builder

I would like to ask for some help with this small program. I'm using Embarcadero RAD XE2 and trying to build a small form with a button and a textbox. The mechanic is simple, I write some stuff in a textbox, and I want that stuff to be written to a .txt file when I click the button.

Here is the code in my .cpp file of the form:

```
 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <fmx.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <String>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "STRTEST.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.fmx"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int writefile(String A)
{
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open("D://example.txt");
  myfile << A;
  myfile.close();
  return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  String mystr = Edit1->Text+';';
  writefile(mystr);
  Form1->Close();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**NOW, I have this problem: In the line "mystr << A;" I get this error.**

> [BCC32 Error] STRTEST.cpp(13): E2094 'operator<<' not implemented in
>   type 'ofstream' for arguments of type 'UnicodeString'   Full parser
>   context
>       STRTEST.cpp(10): parsing: int writefile(UnicodeString)

I don't know exactly what to do. If I replace A with a direct string i.e (mystr << "HI"), the function writefile works flawless and writes the file with that specific string.

Anyone out there knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<<` and `>>` operators for `String` values are only implemented if `VCL_IOSTREAM` is defined in the project.  Even then, it still would not work because you are using `ofstream`, which does not accept Unicode data (`String` is an alias for `UnicodeString` in CB2009+).  You have to use `wofstream` instead, and then use `String::c_str()` to stream the value:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <fmx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#pragma hdrstop
#include "STRTEST.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.fmx"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int writefile(System::String A)
{
    std::wofstream myfile;
    myfile.open(L"D://example.txt");
    myfile << A.c_str();
    myfile.close();
    return 0;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    System::String mystr = Edit1->Text + L";";
    writefile(mystr);
    Close();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```